# How can I get involved in the Ubuntu Ayatana team?

Tags: ayatana

How can I get involved in Ubuntu UX team?
I think that Ubuntu is the most one of the Linux Distros in the world.
Especially, I am interested in Mir, Unity project to make Ubuntu UX.
I am not experienced but I'd like to Ubuntu Graphics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most open source projects, or projects that are otherwise open to third party contributions will publish some sort of development guidelines.  These are all different for each project and controlled by the project maintainers.  You'd need to look through information posted for any particular project to find out how to contribute.

In the case of Ayatana, the main page is located [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ayatana).  From which you can choose browse a project like [the notify OSD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD), which has it's development guide posted at [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines).

> Please realize that some of these pages may be out of date.

In the case of Ayatana projects, it looks like all of the development is taking place on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ayatana) using the Bazaar VCS.  So grabbing a copy of the source and committing your changes to the VCS will be a good start.  You'd then be able to submit those changes via Launchpad.